# Unable to launch a packaged executable as a Windows service via ProcRun

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, executable, procrun

I have a requirement to launch an executable as a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [service](/questions/tagged/service) with help of [procrun](/questions/tagged/procrun).

I followed the below steps.

1. Created a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) named `run.bat`, to create a service.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\prunsrv.exe"  //IS//Test --DisplayName="Test" --Startup=auto --Install="C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\prunsrv.exe"  --StartMode=exe --StartImage="C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\batchSample.exe"  --LogPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Test\logs" --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto
```

2. Created a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), `batchSample.bat`, to launch a URL:

```
start https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3pG6b3uI_E
```

3. Converted the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to an [executable](/questions/tagged/executable), `batchSample.exe`, and placed it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Test`.
4. Executed `run.bat`.

At this point the the windows service, `Test` started without giving any error, but it did not execute the `batchSample.exe` as used for `--StartImage`.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your batch file is not an executable, no matter what extension you give it.

Per the docs - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html

--StartImage        Executable that will be run. Only applies to exe mode.

++StartParams       List of parameters that will be passed to either StartImage or StartClass. Parameters are separated using either # or ; character.

You need a program to execute your batch file as StartImage (sh?), and put the batch file in StartParams.